# Installing NPM/Node on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL). What architecture does Ubuntu/Bash use?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows as the command line tool.

I need to install Node and NPM, and on the [download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) for unix I need to choose between 5 different options: 32bits, 64 bits, ArmV6, ArmV7, Armv8. Arms themselves are either 32 or 64 bit so this left me a confused.

Are Arm versions meant for mobile devices? I couldn't find Bash/Ubuntu in any directory, and not in the 64 bit program directory.

If my Windows is 64 bit, can I assume that Bash/Ubuntu will be 64 bits as well, and that that is the right file to download?

Comment: I got the best olution in this article: https://winsmarts.com/how-to-install-node-on-linux-on-windows-wsl-65069ea5f83d

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To install `node` and `npm` in Ubuntu on WSL you need to install `nvm`. It doesn't work with `apt-install`

1. Install NVM

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash`

2. Edit ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc depending on the Linux Shell you're using and add the following at the bottom

`export NVM_DIR="/home/yourusername/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`

Now restart bash, and then run

`nvm install node`

That will install the latest, if you wish to install a specific version

`nvm install v6.11.5`

You're all set.

Credit : https://winsmarts.com/how-to-install-node-on-linux-on-windows-wsl-65069ea5f83d

Comment: currently on 0.37.2

Comment: This worked for me, but the Step #2 you listed there was already done to my Ubuntu WSL distribution in ~/.bashrc, so I did not need to do it. Likely the automated script was changed since the original post to include that automatically. Thanks for the post!

Comment: You should use the new official NVM distribution link to install NVM. The official install script is `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Any idea as to why i'm getting `unmatched "` on the line `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"` when i start the terminal? Everything still works fine it just looks like an error

Comment: you might need to restart shell after Step1 and Step2 if applicable

Comment: I already had a .bash_profile which is why the .bashrc wasn't working. had to add the export script into .bash_profile. In case if anyone has the same problem

Answer (score 10):

### According to the link of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49919063/installing-npm-node-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-wsl-what-architecture-does-u#comment99437393_50904539)  without NVM

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

As of **december 2021**, it results in:

```
√ tik ~ # npm -v
8.1.4
√ tik ~ # node -v
v17.2.0
```

Answer (score 8):

```
uname -a
```

Run the above command in WSl.

If it is 64 bit it will display the following

```
Linux Karthik-Pc 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #112-Microsoft Thu Jun 07 22:57:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If it is 32 bit then it will display

```
Linux Karthik-Pc 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #112-Microsoft Thu Jun 07 22:57:00 PST 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Btw you can easily download node and npm in wsl from apt.

```
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: I get installed nodejs, and then i run `node --verion` with no problem. but I don't get `npm` command running in WSL Ubuntu

Comment: Follow these instructions for installing node js [link](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: @KarthikRaja They don't work. Output of `which npm` is `/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm`

Comment: @UTF_or_Death were you able to fix this?

Comment: I followed the instructions on https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-enterprise-linux-fedora-and-snap-packages
They have changed since then, but probably work

Comment: Does `apt-get install -y nodejs` install and prepare the `npm` command?

Answer (score 3):

Windows has an official support page on how to do this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl

Their instructions are (all in your WSL terminal):

1. Install `curl` with `sudo apt-get install curl`
2. Install `nvm` with `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash` - Note that this is the **official** place to get NVM from.
3. Restart your terminal.
4. Install a version of node with `nvm install <version>`. For example, I chose `nvm install lts/hydrogen` to install the latest version of Node 18. You can use `nvm ls` to see the available versions.
5. Optionally, you can mark a version as the default using `nvm alias default <version>` so that it's automatically set whenever you open a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the WSL packages and repositories for you to get `nodejs`. Use the following set of commands to accomplish the same:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install nodejs -y
```

Answer (score 1):

## A great alternative to **nvm** is Volta

To install volta

```
curl https://get.volta.sh | bash
```

Volta is pretty cool alternative to **nvm**
To install a specific version of node

```
volta install node@<version>
```

Comment: Perhaps relevant to add why it is superior to nvm - the ability to pin project to node version easily across collaborators?

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering issues even after running `sudo apt install npm`, it's possible that the npm binary is not in your system's PATH. Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. Check if npm is installed:
   After running the installation command, check if npm is installed by running the following command:

   **npm -v**

   If npm is installed, you should see its version number. If you still get a "command not found" error, proceed to the next steps.
2. Verify the npm binary location:
   Find out where npm is installed by checking the path to its binary. You can use the `which` command:

   **which npm**

   This will show the path to the npm binary. If it doesn't return anything, npm may not be installed correctly.
3. Check the npm installation log:
   Review the installation log to see if there were any errors during the installation:

   **cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep npm**

   Look for any error messages that might indicate what went wrong during the installation.
4. Reinstall npm:
   If there are issues, you can try reinstalling npm:

   **sudo apt remove npm && sudo apt install npm**

   After reinstalling, check again if npm is in your PATH and if the issue persists.
5. Verify Node.js installation:
   Sometimes, npm issues can be related to Node.js. Ensure that Node.js is installed:

   **node -v**

   If Node.js is not installed, you can install it using the following command:

   **sudo apt install nodejs**

   Then, retry installing npm:

   **sudo apt install npm**

There you goooo!!!

Comment: Are you aware of [our policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?

Answer (score -1):

Try to upgrade all your plugins in apk. Run the below command in WSl.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Yes absolutely! Followed by `sudo apt install nodejs`